# What is the use of the rowKey attribute in Primefaces' p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I tried to select rows in a `p:dataTable`, however it shows an error. After I added a value for the `rowKey` attribute of `p:dataTable`, the error rectified. I thus wonder what the actual use of the `rowKey` attribute is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I quote PrimeFaces reference guide:

> RowKey should be a unique identifier from your data model and used by datatable to find the selected rows. You can either define this key by
>   using the rowKey attribute or by binding a data model which implements
>   org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel.

So if your datatable is set by collection of beans, rowKey should  be the attributte which uniquely represents that bean, e.g a property representing a primary key of a database.